# Headset jack - mic not detected

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headset

I'm trying to use my headset on desktop but the microphone is not detected by Ubuntu and the speakers work fine. Any tips would be very much appreciated. Here are some info:

**dmesg | grep sound**

```
[   22.869057] input: HDA Intel PCH Headset Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input29
[   22.869127] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input30
```

**cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf**

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci

options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2

#Line I've added in effort to fix it
options snd-hda-intel model=alc255-acer,dell-headset-multi
```

PulseAudio Volume Controll shows that Headset Microphone is unplugged even though it is connected
[image: PulseAudio Volume Controll]

After connecting the headset for the first time I've had this kind of popup. This change has occured after adding `options snd-hda-intel model=alc255-acer,dell-headset-multi` to `alsa-base.conf` 
[image: Message after connecting the headset]

Sadly after selecting "Headset" nothing changes

Comment: Just in case (it was actually detected), did you check the Gnome sound settings (another input line might be selected).

Comment: It's very weird as it detects that I have a headset jack but for example in PulseAudio Volume Controll in Input Devices category in field Port (Internal Microphone is set as default) I have "Headset Microphone (unplugged)". Also for the first time I had a popup window after connecting the headset that reads "Set Audio Device" with two options "Headphones" and "Headset". Unfortunately the Headset option still makes no difference in input devices :c

Comment: Additional info needs to be added to the question not made as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally I've got it to work! Using the `dmesg | grep sound` I saw that the output address was 1B so then in an act of desperation I've overwritten that pin address using `hdajackretask` as a "Microphone".
[image]

Then click on "Install boot override" and reboot!